# Google play says "your device isn't compatible with this version" in all devices but works fine from eclipse adb

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

This is my android manifest file.I worked fine from the eclipse. I have uploaded my apk in google play store. It says the message "your device isn't compatible with this version" in all devices.But it is listed in the supporting devices.  Please help me. I am testing with the device android 4.4.4

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

     <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.rymm.classnet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.rymm.classnet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: You probably have a debug version of your app already installed on your device for testing. Uninstall that and then try again.

Comment: I even did that. but no use.

Comment: Have you solved your issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have `uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"` twice in your manifest. The first declaration sets `android:required="false"`, however the second declaration will use the default which is `android:required="true"`.

Also your manifest lists `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` which will also use the default required value, `android:required="true"`.

Therefore if your device does not have an autofocus camera it will be listed as not compatible in the play store.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will remove the line autofocus tag, and will give a try

Comment: That did not help me..is there anything that I need to do other than this?